# P5.JS & HTML - How to use p5 sliders in HTML to layout them

Tags: javascript, html, slider, p5.js

to showcase my idea, here is an image of my program.

[image: image of my program]

On the right you can see two columns with multiple rows of sliders. Since I'm new to p5 I've unfortunately created them in p5 through (createSlider, createCheckbox,...).
My goal is to just simply writing them in multiple lines of html code for easier positioning. In the end, I wanna have a container which I can scale according to the screenHeight.

I was wondering if there is an option to refer to my js variables in html.

Here's a small overview of my bad code:

```
  checkStroke = createCheckbox('Enable Stroke', true)
  checkStroke.position(sliderSecondCol,sliderFirstRow+120)
  sliderStrokeAmount = createSlider(0,0.5,0.04,0.0001)
  sliderStrokeAmount.position(sliderFirstCol,sliderFirstRow+140)
  sliderStrokeHue = createSlider(0,360,200);
  sliderStrokeHue.position(sliderFirstCol,sliderFirstRow+160);
  sliderStrokeSat = createSlider(0,100,30);
  sliderStrokeSat.position(sliderFirstCol,sliderFirstRow+180);
  sliderStrokeBri = createSlider(0,100,100);
  sliderStrokeBri.position(sliderFirstCol,sliderFirstRow+200);
  sliderStrokeAlpha = createSlider(0,1,1,0.0001);
  sliderStrokeAlpha.position(sliderFirstCol,sliderFirstRow+220);
```

I hope I made my point clear enough, and really hope for some help.
It's for a university project, and it's my first time doing such a "big" programming.

Thanks Max

Comment: As a rule, please post actual code (properly formatted using indentation or ```) instead of a screen shot of the code.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question "is [there] an option to refer to my js variables in html" is, in short, no. In order to have HTML elements automatically updated with values from JavaScript variables you either need to use a front end framework like ReactJS or Angular that would facilitate that via templating and data binding, or you need custom JavaScript that updates the HMTL elements.

Given your description of what you want: to declare your HTML elements as HTML rather than create them via p5.js functions; and the implicit requirement that you need to access and update these from JavaScript; I would suggest you look at the [`select()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/select) in p5.js. This will allow you to get a `p5.Element` reference to each of your HTML elements based on their `id` attribute (via `select('#your-slider-id')`) at which point the rest of your code, that uses the values of these inputs or subscribes to change events, can remain the same.

Example:

```js
let slider1;
let slider2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  slider1 = select('#slider1');
  slider2 = select('#slider2');
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  translate(width / 4, height / 2);
  ellipse(0, 0, slider1.value(), slider2.value());
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [sliders] auto 20px [labels] auto;
}

#controls input {
  grid-column: sliders;
}

#controls label {
  grid-column: labels;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" />
  <label for="slider1">Slider #1</label>
  <input id="slider2" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" />
  <label for="slider2">Slider Two</label>
</div>
```

Comment: So you would rather declare the sliders in HTML and then access them in p5? Did I get that right?

Comment: Couldn't I also make like : HTML <p id = scaleslider></p> ; JS sliderScale.parent('scaleslider') ?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly also use the `parent()` function to inject your sliders into a specific container element so that you can control layout with CSS instead of absolute positioning.

Comment: It worked for me with the sliders and the checkboxes. But now I have the problem with my canvas. I can't parent it to my grid. It will just not appear. Is there an option in HTML where I can create a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use HTML sliders and then connect them to JavaScript.

HTML slider with minimum input 1, maximum input 100, and start value 50 in a container:

```html
<div id="sliderContainer" >
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="slider">
</div>
```

And then add JavaScript in script tags:

```html
<script>
let slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let header = document.getElementById("demo");

slider.oninput = function() {
  header.innerHTML = slider.value;
}
</script>
```

Put it all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="demo">50</h1>

<div id="sliderContainer" >
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="slider">
</div>

<script>
let slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let header = document.getElementById("demo");

slider.oninput = function() {
  header.innerHTML = slider.value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions on how to add p5.js to this, let me know and I will create an example project for you to download and toy around with. Don't be afraid to ask! :)

Sources:
[W3Schools HTML Sliders](http://%3Cdiv%20class=%22slidecontainer%22%3E%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type=%22range%22%20min=%221%22%20max=%22100%22%20value=%2250%22%20class=%22slider%22%20id=%22myRange%22%3E%20%3C/div%3E)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great example and solution. Can I use the same line: in a separate JS file that is connected to my HTML?

Comment: Absolutely! You can connect it in <head> using <script src="script.js"></script>
(replace script.js with the name of your script.)